# Works in jsFiddle but not on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var add_time = function ($category) {
    'use strict';

    var time_element = $('<input size="7" class="time" placeholder="00:00" pattern="(?:(?:\\d:)?[0-5])?\\d:[0-5]\\d" title="Please insert a time in the form of [[h:]m]m:ss." />');

    if ($('.time').length === 0) {
        time_element.insertAfter($category.find('.add_time_button'));
    } else {
        time_element.insertAfter($('.time'));
    }
};

$('.add_time_button').click(function () {
    'use strict';

    add_time($(this).parentsWhen('.category'));
});
```

I don't get it. No console errors. Everything looks fine to me. Ran it through JSFiddle. Nothing. Sigh. The question is all in the title. Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gtr053/N2HmG/

To future readers, this will be a 404 someday soon. Live site: http://bama.ua.edu/~tscrompton/annotation/

Comment: And how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: In the jsFiddle, the code is running `onload`. I'm guessing it isn't on your live site.

Comment: @amnotiam, added link to question.

Comment: ...confirmed. Your code is in the `<head>`, with nothing to delay it until after the DOM is ready.

Comment: @amnotiam, so I need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Comment: @TylerCrompton: That's one option. Another is to move the script down to the end of the `body` element, just before its closing tag. Really just anything to ensure that the `.add_time_button` exist when it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsfiddle surrounds your javascript in a `onLoad`. On your site, where are you putting the javascript? In the head section? If so, that's why it's not working. You have to assign your onclicks and all that jazz after the elements load.

**EDIT:**

In your javascript file you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //put the javascript from the jsfiddle in here
});
```