# Jquery plugin working in JSfiidle and not in my page

Tags: jquery, onload, jsfiddle

There is something i am missing on this jquery plugin which works in jsfiddle and not in my page.

This is a Jquery plugin for cash Register effect. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/13/) and you can see this effect on the number below VALOR LIQUIDATIVO.

I have pasted the same code in my [page](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Producto.html), but the plugin is not working. There is probably an issue about the option to run the script code "onload" as i have seen in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637873/code-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-browser)
but i am not figuring out the problem. How i have to modify the file for my browser?

Comment: Have you checked that you're using the same version of jQuery on your page an on JSfiddle?

Comment: yes i am using the same version of jQuery, it should be an issue about the .onload option, i guess..

Comment: So, you copied the code directly from jsfiddle into your page?  I would recommend deleting that block and copying it from another source; jsfiddle has a habit of putting in invisible characters that can (and sometimes will) break code.

Comment: it 's probably an issue similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236234/works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-on-live-site , the code i have copied in jsfiidle is at the end of the body, i am doing as reccomended

Comment: Most probably you have an invisible character at the end of your code block, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on line `Producto.html:347`, as `Daedalus` mentioned already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be a syntax error.  Usually javascript will break if a syntax error is found, and although I don't really have any way to test if this is the case, I believe this to be your problem.

As I said in the comments, when copying data from jsfiddle to an actual script, it tends to copy in invisible characters that can break things, due to the way jsfiddle formats text.

When I copied your code, from your webpage, into Notepad++(a code editor), I found a hidden character directly after your function call, on line `347`.  This of course showed up as a question mark, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#valorliquidativo').cashRegister();

});​
  ^ hidden character directly after this semi-colon
```

Chrome's javascript console says the above is an illegal character, so delete that line, type it out manually, and try again.  See if it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of the copy and paste from `jsfiddle` in my `notepad++`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#valorliquidativo').cashRegister();
});? //<---
```

Notice the `?`, it's being pasted with the code block and made the error appear. try to delete the empty line in your code block using `backspace` or manually write this code block.

Comment: I have deleted and copied it manually and it works fine. Thanks so much