# Jquery Plugin Cashregister Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I was suggested to try out this simple [jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/alonzzzo/cashRegister/blob/master/jquery.cashRegister.js) to give a cash register effect to the number

First i wanted to test in in [jsfiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XT7rr/1/) to see how it works but something goes wrong 
because i dont get any effect. The only modification i have made to the plugin is the following:

```
 easing: 'swing',
duration: 1700,
```

and not

```
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: 700,
```

I dont understand what i am doing wrong, or there is something broken in the plugin?

Comment: Does seem kinda broken. Debugging to see what's up. Do you know if there are any example usages of the plug-in online?

Comment: that's the problem , there are not examples to check it out, really poor documentation in Github for this plugin

Comment: I never use a jquery plugin unless i see a working example online. too many crappy, not working plug-ins.

Comment: What kind of cash register effect are you looking for?

Comment: In other words, can you explain exactly what you are looking to get? If you are just looking for a currency formatting... javascript by itself does that really easily.

Comment: I basically need to find a Jquery Plugin for cash effect that i can use also with number who have "," and "." This is a plugin i have used http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/14/ but unfortunately as you can see in the jsfiddle, the plugin is not configured with numbers who have "," and "." inside.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your jsFiddle.  It will never work without this.

Comment: You need to include the parameters for finalValue and opts

Comment: i did it then but it does not work yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery plugin working in JSfiidle and not in my page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560637/jquery-plugin-working-in-jsfiidle-and-not-in-my-page).  Please do not post the same issue multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't working at all for you because you were not using the function parameters correctly.

But even if you do that correctly --- This plug-in is very bad. Works very poorly.

Try this one instead:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

Working example (i tested it and it works beautifully)

http://www.bendewey.com/code/formatcurrency/demo/

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery FormatCurrency Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, div  { margin:0px auto; padding:0px; }

            .main { margin:40px; }

            .sample { float:left; margin:10px; padding:4px; border:1px solid #888; width:350px; }

            .sample h3 { margin:-4px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:4px; background:#555; color:#eee; }

            .currencyLabel { display:block; }        
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Sample 1
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#currencyButton').click(function()
                {
                    $('#currencyField').formatCurrency();
                    $('#currencyField').formatCurrency('.currencyLabel');
                });
            });

            // Sample 2
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.currency').blur(function()
                {
                    $('.currency').formatCurrency();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="formPage">
            <h1>Format Currency Sample</h1>

            <div class="sample">
                <h3>Formatting Using Button Click</h3>
                <input type="textbox" id="currencyField" value="$1,220.00" />
                <input type="button" id="currencyButton" value="Convert" />

                <div>
                    Formatting Currency to an Html Span tag.
                    <span class="currencyLabel">$1,220.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sample">
                <h3>Formatting Using Blur (Lost Focus)</h3>

                <input type="textbox" id="currencyField" class='currency' value="$1,220.00" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i am trying out here...have a look, i don t get the number in the div :( http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/16/ Thanks for your time

Comment: I thought that plug-in was working, but nope it was not even formatting the correct dollar amount after I edited it!!! Use the google-code plugin I supplied in my editted answer instead.

Comment: Yes it s working and thanks for your great work, just the last question, it happens to you too that if i put the number in the div and not here $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cash').cashRegister(1000000);
});, it doesn t make the register cash effect? look http://jsfiddle.net/z2qps/17/